# Manually install SSH service

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a CCTV camera DVR at work that only allows local login for DVR software management via a command line console (looks like a GUI you'd get on a serial console) or web login for viewing the cameras. I'd like to be able to SSH into it, but I don't know what flavor of *nix it is, nor can I login to a prompt to install packages. I can, however, remove the hard drive.

If I get the drive mounted on a separate machine such that I can copy files to it, would it be possible to copy config and executable files to it in order to have an SSH server?

Comment: *If* you can get the drive mounted *and* it's running some Unix variant, then yes. But if you don't even know what OS it's running, it's hard to see how we could help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Unix doesn't seem to be involved in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the device locally, use another machine on the network to port forward to the device, port `80` for web or `22` for ssh are generic. try

```
netcat -z <ip_address> 80 && echo TRUE || echo FALSE
```

to check if port `80` is open, swap `80` for `22` or whatever port to test.

If you have another machine on local network with ssh, to port forward do:

```
ssh user@example.com -L 50000:192.168.0.10:80
```

- where `50000` is the local port you use to connect to remote device. eg for web in you browser you'd type `localhost:50000` providing `localhost` is mapped to `127.0.0.1` in your `hosts` file
- where `192.168.0.10` is the local ip address of camera device you want to connect to remotely
- and `80` is the camera device's local port you want forward